# Converting from SQL statements to SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, relational-database

Thanks in advance for your help. I have to convert the following SQL statements to SQL alchemy. I haven't used SQL Alchemy before.

SQL:

```
SELECT User.id, User.nicknames
FROM users, breadcrumbs
WHERE user_id in my_friend_ids
AND user_id = bc.creator_id
AND bc.location_id = loc_id

my_friend_ids = select friend_id from friends 
                where user_id = requestor_id and status ='approved'
```

What I have got so far:

```
my_friend_ids =  select([Friend.user_id]).select_from(Friend).\
                 where(and_(Friend.friend_id == user_id,
                 Friend.status == 'approved'))
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How do I convert the above SQL statements to SQL Alchemy (similar to the way I did it for my_friend_ids)?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a subquery.

```
my_friend_ids = db.session.query( Friend.id ).filter( and_(
    Friend.friend_id == Breadcrumb.creator_id,
    Friend.status == 'approved'
) ).subquery()

q = db.session.query( User, Breadcrumb ).filter( and_(
    User.id.in_( my_friend_ids ),
    Breadcrumb.location_id == loc_id
).all()
```

Now q will contain both the user and breadcrumbs objects that fit the query (accessible via `q[index].User` and `q[index].Breadcrumb` resepectively).  This is not very efficient though.  You should probably do this as a join instead.